# Why do some elements in Chrome Developer Tools 'elements' tab not appear in 'view page source?'

Tags: google-chrome

**Summary of Question:** In what scenarios would DOM elements one might find in chrome developer tools 'element' view not appear in the 'view page source' page and vice-versa? Are there any other pitfalls I should be aware about?

**Details**

I was following an introduction to the nodejs cheerio module and I was analysing [this page](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2297585/Wild-squirrels-pose-charming-pictures-photographer-hides-nuts-miniature-props.html) to find ways to identify the main image elements.

I noticed the following pattern under chrome developer tools:

```
div class="artSplitter"
  div class="image-wrap style="cursor: pointer;"
     img src="whatever.jpg" class="blkBorder"
```

The div image-wrap element is missing in the page source but appears in the elements tab of chrome developer tools!

To quickly check this out, I'm looking at this image in particular. Just C-F to it in the source: http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/03/22/article-2297585-18DB1B03000005DC-745_634x421.jpg

I really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe "View Source" shows the original page markup. Any elements added or removed by JavaScript/AJAX probably would not show up in "View Source". However, they would be visible in the developer console.

Comment: I tried to think about it but I do not understand... why? Why is chrome's source different than the source of the 'view page source'?

Comment: As far as I know, "View Source" only shows the initial state of the page. It's a one and done deal. It will not update with changes. However, for the developer tools to be accurate, they have to update to corresponding DOM changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there are *tags* in HTML source code and *elements* in the DOM tree. When browser loads a page, it creates an element per tag (roughly). This translation process is not that simple, so, for example, `table` element gets inner `tbody` element, even if `tbody` tag wasn't present in HTML. Then JavaScript on the loaded page can do whatever it wants with your DOM tree. The reason "page source" window and "elements" tab differ is that the first one shows HTML source code, and the second one shows DOM tree.

Comment: If I understand DOM vs html source, DOM is an object that represents HTML. So 'view source' shows raw html and dev tools 'elements'... for lack of better words, translates the DOM tree (as it is updated...adding in War10ck's explanation) to html and shows that?