# Cant access element that are shown in developer tools but not in page source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, developer-tools

I have the same problem that is stated in below link, but i am looking for a way to access those elements (using jquery) that are not present in page source but are visible in developer tools. Please suggest some ideas.

[Why do some elements in Chrome Developer Tools 'elements' tab not appear in 'view page source?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304403/why-do-some-elements-in-chrome-developer-tools-elements-tab-not-appear-in-vie)

Here is the actual problem -
I have hosted "Powerpivot chart" in sharepoint "Excel web part".Whenever user clicks on the chart(which is an img tag shown in developer tools) that is embedded in excel webpart, I have zoomout that img.

In Developer tools i see below code:

```
<div id="ctl00ctl00_sheetContentDiv" class="ewr-sheetcontainer ewr-grdblkcontainer ewa-scrollbars" role="presentation">
    <div class="ewafo" id="ctl00_ctl35_g_ec06c24e_5aac_4ae3_af75_93564d395086_ctl01_ctl00__0_1.11.0" style="top: 133px; left: 327px; width: 480px; height: 274px; z-index: 50;">
        <div class="ewa-fo-img-div" style="visibility: visible;">   
            <img src="http://mydummyserverlink" title="Excel chart or image" alt="Excel chart or image" onerror="_ewa_oile(this,'Failed to download chart or image');" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;        border: 0px; display: block;" usemap="#ctl00_ctl35_g_ec06c24e_5aac_4ae3_af75_93564d395086_ctl01_ctl00_imagemap_1.11.0_3"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In View Source I see only the outer div:

```
<div id="ctl00ctl00_sheetContentDiv" class="ewr-sheetcontainer ewr-grdblkcontainer ewa-scrollbars" role="presentation"></div>
```

In fact I am trying to access the div using its class "ewr-sheetcontainer" like

```
$(".ewr-sheetcontainer")
```

But it is returning what it has in view source.

Thanks in advance,
Madhu M.

Comment: And which elements are you talking about? Provide relevant code in question itself!

Comment: Didn't that link answer your question ?

Comment: If you can see them, you can access them using jQuery selectors

Comment: That link say to access the elements using DOM. var dom=$(".ewa-fo-img-div").get(0);
alert($(dom).length); but it returns 0.

Comment: Not sure what this means? "Whenever user clicks on the chart(which is an img tag shown in developer tools) that is embedded in excel webpart, I have zoomout that img."

Answer (score -1):

If an element is present in devtools, then you should be able to access them with standard methods.

With the example given in your link, if we have

```
<table id='mytable'>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
</table>
```

`<tbody>` is not in the original code. However, it is interpreted by the browser as:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell1</td>
            <td>cell2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can still use CSS or JavaScript (jQuery) selectors to access `<tbody>`.

jquery

```
$('#mytable tbody')...
```

css

```
#mytable tbody { ... }
```

If this example isn't relevant to you, then please post your relevant HTML for us to look at more closely.

---

With your updated question, my guess is that you are trying to select that parent container before it has any children in it. Try wrapping your selector in a `document.ready` or some other function that would make sure the content is already loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ewr-sheetcontainer')
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have updated my question. Plz suggest some idea.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have tried the same approach but couldnot able to read it. In this http://asurkov.blogspot.com/2012/02/aria-hidden-and-rolepresentation.html link it says role="presentaion" means element will get removed from accessible tree. So which means I cannot access it? is there any alternative for this??