# how to access elements that are shown in developer tools but not in source code VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm trying to access a Link on this site: https://finder.fi/search?what=sonera. the link is the first result of the page. The part of code in the developer tools is like this:

```
<a class="SearchResult__ProfileLink" href="/Televiestint%C3%A4laitteita+ja+palveluja/Sonera/Helsinki/yhteystiedot/175522?what=sonera" data-track-link="profileLink" data-reactid=".27sinr99zb4.0:1.0.2.5:$0.1.1.0"><div class="SearchResult__Name" data-reactid=".27sinr99zb4.0:1.0.2.5:$0.1.1.0.0">Sonera</div></a>
```

However none of this can be found in the source code. 
**How do I access the code shown in the developer tools?** This is my code so far.

```
Sub test()
Dim browserIE As Object
Set browserIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
browserIE.Top = 0
browserIE.Left = 800
browserIE.Width = 800
browserIE.Height = 1200
browserIE.Visible = True
browserIE.navigate ("https://finder.fi/search?what=sonera")
Do While browserIE.ReadyState <> 4 And browserIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
```

I've already done some research (e.g. [Cant access element that are shown in developer tools but not in page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589025/cant-access-element-that-are-shown-in-developer-tools-but-not-in-page-source)) but haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: are there any frames?

Comment: If it's not in the source code then it's not in the DOM, so you can't.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the developer tools is the HTML contents of the page `"https://finder.fi/search?what=sonera"`. If you want to access the HTML of this page, you can navigate the DOM (Document Object Model) of the HTML page. If you google for "InternetExplorer.Application" you will find links to MSDN with all required information.

To access the document:

```
Dim oDoc As Object
Set oDoc = BrowserIE.Document
```

To find all the links on the page:

```
Dim cLinks
cLinks = oDoc.body.getElementsByTagName("A")
```

This latter needs some trying and debuggin by you. MSDN says it returns a collection but does not provide an example for VBA. So the Dim might need to be `Dim cLinks As Collection`.