# How to check if all target attribute has rel attribute in anchor tag? (view source and elements tab in developer tool)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to create a test script for a page , but there's a difference in view source(ctrl U) and elements tab in developers tool.

I'm just a freshmen with this.

i have similar problem with this :
[Why do some elements in Chrome Developer Tools 'elements' tab not appear in 'view page source?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304403/why-do-some-elements-in-chrome-developer-tools-elements-tab-not-appear-in-vie)

but for me : is there a way that will check each of the elements tab instead of view source?

in HTML View source there are :

```
<a href='link.html' target="_blank" >Text</a>
<a href='link.html' target="_blank" rel="noopener">Text</a>
<a href='link.html' target="_blank" rel="noopener">Text</a>
```

Elements tab developers tool :

```
<a href='link.html' target="_blank" rel="noopener">Text</a>
<a href='link.html' target="_blank" rel="noopener">Text</a>
<a href='link.html' target="_blank" rel="noopener">Text</a>
```

i have tried this

```
if($('a[target]').attr('rel') === undefined){ //will check 'a' that has 'target' and check if there are rel.
aler('there are target has no rel')
}else{
alert('there are rel in all target')
} 

//but this will triggered in view source.
```

I am expecting that the output of it will passed based on the element section
that the all 'a' with 'target' has 'rel'. Thank you so much.

Comment: `if($('a[target]').attr('rel') === undefined)` will not do a loop. You need a `for each`

Answer (score 0):

Try this as you need to pass all through in a loop -

```
$('a[target]').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('rel') === undefined){
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: ,yes indeed this will loop but this will triggered also into view source ,,can we make it into the elements tab ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those with:

```
$('a[target]:not([rel])')
```

Comment: That's css. It will select a elements with a target attribute and no rel attribute.